# Android webview get sslError SSL_UNTRUSTED but certificate is valid

Tags: android, ssl, https, webview, webviewclient

I've implemented `onReceivedSslError` method in my WebViewClient to properly handle invalid https certificate in webview:

```
@Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebActivity.this);
            String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
            }
            message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";

            builder.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("continue", (dialog, which) -> handler.proceed());
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", (dialog, which) -> handler.cancel());
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
```

When the webview loads my webpage the `SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED` error is being detected. However if I open the same exact url in chrome (both desktop or mobile) the certificate is considered valid and trusted:

[image: Google Chrome certificate popup]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Java doesn't use Chrome's truststore. It has its own. Your message should read 'the *certificate* is not trusted.'

Comment: i am having the same problem.... on chrome or any other browser the url opens (pc and mobile) however on the webview in my app it gives me primary error3 : untrusted certificate.. any luck with this one?

you can use onReceivedSslError but on production google play store will not let you publish your app... i read that android stopped oauth2 login(my url has a verification username and password confirmation)!!

did you solved it?!

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 13):

For me this was an issue with the server I was trying to reach. It had a broken intermediate certificate chain. It was the redirect server that had a broken chain.
When there is a broken chain the webview has no way to resolve because it does not know where to look for the correct cert.

[Use this tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to check for common misconfigurations. Be sure to check any redirects as well.

Android does not support [Authority Information Access](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1)

And therefore there is no [AIA Fetching](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/aia-fetching/)

**But?!.. it works in browsers**
Yes, It works in browsers because all browsers carry around a list of intermediates to fall back on when the cert has a broken chain.

**Solution:** Fix certificate chain on server.

Answer (score 5):

Even for me it was giving SSL_UNTRUSTED when the cert was throwing invalid CN(SSL_IDMISMATCH) on android chrome.
Added [network-security-config](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) and all seemed to work fine.
For me I installed a user-ca which wasnt being picked up by webview.

Added this snippet of code, which allowed me to use user-ca installed in user credentials.

```
<network-security-config>  
  <base-config>  
        <trust-anchors>  
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->  
            <certificates src="system" />  
            <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->  
            <certificates src="user" />  
       </trust-anchors>  
  </base-config>  
</network-security-config>
```